Servidor SFTP NodeJs
Estoy intentando implementar un SFTP con nodejs pero tengo este error al intentar conectarme desde filezilla, que estoy haciendo mal?
CODIGO EN LOS COMENTARIOS
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2


const { readFileSync, writeFileSync, existsSync, mkdirSync } = require('fs');
const { inspect } = require('util');
const { Server } = require('ssh2');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

const OPEN_MODE = { WRITE: 0x0002 };
const STATUS_CODE = {
  OK: 0,
  FAILURE: 4,
};

const allowedUser = Buffer.from('foo');
const allowedPassword = Buffer.from('bar');

function checkValue(input, allowed) {
  const autoReject = (input.length !== allowed.length);
  if (autoReject) {
    allowed = input;
  }
  const isMatch = timingSafeEqual(input, allowed);
  console.log(`Checking values: ${input.toString()} vs ${allowed.toString()}, Auto reject: ${autoReject}, Is match: ${isMatch}`);
  return (!autoReject && isMatch);
}

function generateSSHKeys() {
  const keyDir = path.join(__dirname, 'keys');
  const privateKeyPath = path.join(keyDir, 'id_rsa');
  const publicKeyPath = path.join(keyDir, 'id_rsa.pub');

  if (!existsSync(keyDir)) {
    mkdirSync(keyDir);
    console.log(`Directorio creado: ${keyDir}`);
  }

  execSync(`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ${privateKeyPath} -N ""`);
  console.log('Claves SSH generadas:', privateKeyPath, publicKeyPath);
}

const privateKeyFile = path.join(__dirname, 'keys', 'id_rsa');
if (!existsSync(privateKeyFile)) {
  console.log(`No existe la clave privada, generando claves SSH en: ${privateKeyFile}`);
  generateSSHKeys();
} else {
  console.log(`La clave privada ya existe en: ${privateKeyFile}`);
}

new Server({
  hostKeys: [readFileSync(privateKeyFile)]
}, (client) => {
  console.log('¡Cliente conectado!');

  client.on('authentication', (ctx) => {
    console.log(`Autenticación de cliente: ${ctx.username}`);
    
    let allowed = true;
    if (!checkValue(Buffer.from(ctx.username), allowedUser)) {
      allowed = false;
      console.log('Usuario no permitido.');
    }

    switch (ctx.method) {
      case 'password':
        if (!checkValue(Buffer.from(ctx.password), allowedPassword)) {
          console.log('Contraseña incorrecta.');
          return ctx.reject();
        }
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Método de autenticación no soportado: ${ctx.method}`);
        return ctx.reject();
    }

    if (allowed) {
      ctx.accept();
      console.log('Autenticación aceptada.');
    } else {
      ctx.reject();
      console.log('Autenticación rechazada.');
    }
  }).on('ready', () => {
    console.log('¡Cliente autenticado!');

    client.on('session', (accept, reject) => {
      const session = accept();
      session.on('sftp', (accept, reject) => {
        console.log('Sesión SFTP del cliente');
        const openFiles = new Map();
        let handleCount = 0;
        const sftp = accept();

        sftp.on('OPEN', (reqid, filename, flags, attrs) => {
          const handle = Buffer.alloc(4);
          openFiles.set(handleCount, true);
          handle.writeUInt32BE(handleCount++, 0);
          console.log(`Abriendo archivo: ${filename}`);
          sftp.handle(reqid, handle);
        }).on('WRITE', (reqid, handle, offset, data) => {
          if (handle.length !== 4 || !openFiles.has(handle.readUInt32BE(0))) {
            console.log(`Fallo al escribir: handle inválido ${handle}`);
            return sftp.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.FAILURE);
          }
          sftp.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.OK);
          console.log(`Escribir en archivo en el offset ${offset}: ${inspect(data)}`);
        }).on('CLOSE', (reqid, handle) => {
          let fnum;
          if (handle.length !== 4 || !openFiles.has(fnum = handle.readUInt32BE(0))) {
            console.log(`Fallo al cerrar: handle inválido ${handle}`);
            return sftp.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.FAILURE);
          }
          console.log('Cerrando archivo');
          openFiles.delete(fnum);
          sftp.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.OK);
        });
      });
    });
  }).on('close', () => {
    console.log('Cliente desconectado');
  });
}).listen(22, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('Escuchando en el puerto ' + this.address().port);
});


Buenas tardes, cuando muestras "metodo de autenticacion no soportado: none" podria ser que este configurado FileZilla para conectarse sin credenciales y por eso se rechace ya que tu le estas pasando unas claves?
Un saludo.
Aparte de eso, si te conectas por consola con sftp del tipo user@ip funciona correctamente?
